Laplace transform of exponential functions with derivatives.
I have been trying to calculate the Laplace transform of these troublesome exponential functions:
Having $\alpha \in \mathbb{R^+}$
1.$\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{n \alpha t}\frac{f(t)}{t^2} \right\},n \in \mathbb{C}$,
2.$\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{n \alpha t}f''(t) \right\}$
let  $n \in \mathbb{C}$ and
3.$\mathcal{L}\left\{\left(1+e^{k r}\right)^{-1/2} f(r) \right\} , k \in \mathbb{R^+}$
What we know:
From the books Integrals and series: direct laplace transforms of Prudnikov et al. and  Tables of Laplace transforms of Oberhettinger et al.
$\mathcal{L}\left\{t^{-m}f(t)\right\} = \int_s^\infty... \int_s^\infty F(s) (ds)^{m}=\int_s^\infty \frac{(\lambda-s)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} F(\lambda) \, d\lambda$
$\mathcal{L}\left\{f''(s)\right\} = s^2F(s)-sf(0)-f'(0)$
Thus:
$\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{f(t)}{t^2}\right\} = \int_s^\infty \int_s^\infty F(s) (ds)^{2}=\int_s^\infty (\lambda-s) F(\lambda) \, d\lambda \\$
First Transform:
By using the definition of Laplace transforms..
$\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{n \alpha t}\frac{f(t)}{t^2} \right\} = \int_0^\infty e^{-st} e^{n \alpha t}\frac{f(t)}{t^2} dt=  \int_0^\infty e^{-(s-n \alpha)t} \frac{f(t)}{t^2} \, dt$
If we let $p=s-na$ since $s$ is already complex, adding other complex $n\alpha$ should not affect the r variable in the integral.
$\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{n \alpha t}\frac{f(t)}{t^2} \right\} = \int_0^\infty e^{-pt} \frac{ f(t)}{t^2} \, dt = \int_p^\infty (\lambda-p) F(\lambda) \, d\lambda \\      
 \phantom{\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{n \alpha t}\frac{f(t)}{t^2} \right\}}=\int_{(s-n \alpha)}^\infty (\lambda-(s-n \alpha)) F(\lambda) \, d\lambda \\$
Seems to be fine. But I still wonder if this is the way to go with it.
Second Transform:
$\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{n \alpha t} f''(t) \right\} = \int_0^\infty e^{-st} e^{n \alpha t}f''(t) dt=  \int_0^\infty e^{-(s-n \alpha)t} f''(t) \, dt$
using a similar argument as in 1), we let $p=s-na$
$\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{n \alpha t}f''(t) \right\} = \int_0^\infty e^{-pt} f''(t) \, dt = p^2F(p)-pf(0)-f'(0) \\      
 \phantom{\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{n \alpha t}\frac{f(t)}{t^2} \right\}}=(s-na)^2F(s-na)-(s-na)f(0)-f'(0) $
Third transform
Regarding the 3rd Laplace transform I am a little confused on a way in which I could try to solve it. So any idea on how to do it would be very appreciated.
